# Colocar resultado de multiplicação em outro input e somar os Totais

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Meu objetivo é exibir a soma dos Inputs na Coluna Total no input "Total do Pedido", onde deverá estar também somado o Acrescimo(será passado na forma decimal(%)) e o valor de desconto(será passado na forma decimal(%)).

Tentei seguir a logica do javascript apresentado usando addEventListener e parentElement mas não logrei exito.

Conto com o apoio dos senhores.

**Segue Abaixo o javascript**

```
window.onload = function () {
var preco = document.getElementById('preco');
var quant = document.getElementById('quant');
var total = document.getElementById('total[]');
var table = document.getElementById('tb_vendas');



/**/
function getMoney( str )
{
        return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
}
function formatReal( int )
{
        var tmp = int+'';
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
        if( tmp.length > 6 )
                tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

        return tmp;
}
/**/
table.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var quant = e.target.matches('[name="quant[]"]') && e.target;
  var tr = quant.parentElement;
  while (tr = tr.parentElement) {
    if (tr.matches('tr')) break;
  }
  var preco = tr.querySelector('[name="preco[]"]');
  var total = tr.querySelector('[name="total[]"]');
  total.value = formatReal(Number(preco.value) * Number(quant.value)*100);
});

}
```

**Agora segue o HTML:**

```
<form action="salvar_venda.php" name="form_venda">
<label>Acrescimo(%):</label>
<input name="acrescimo" id="acrescimo" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<label>Desconto(%):</label>
<input name="desconto" id="desconto" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<label>Total do Pedido(Soma dos totais da tabela+acrescimo(%)-desconto(%))</label>
<input name="desconto" id="desconto" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<table width="200" border="1" id="tb_vendas" name="tb_vendas">
  <tr>
    <td>PRODUTO</td>
    <td>VALOR</td>
    <td>QUANTIDADE</td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 01 </td>
    <td>
        123,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 02</td>
     <td>
        456,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 03</td>
     <td>
        356,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 04</td>
     <td>
        322,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Oi Paulo, editei a resposta, dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usas `onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp[" quantidade "]; ?>);"` estás a impedir o valor da quantidade mudar, ou seja o segundo argumento dessa função nunca muda, mesmo que o input mude.

Sugiro outra abordagem:

```js
var preco = document.getElementById('preco');
var quant = document.getElementById('quant');
var total = document.getElementById('total[]');

quant.addEventListener('input', function() {
  total.value = Number(preco.value) * Number(quant.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="preco" name="preco[]" value="50" />
<input type="number" name="quant[]" id="quant" class="form-control prc " min="1" max="10" step="1">
<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" class="form-control" value="0">
```

Se tens várias linhas de uma tabela com esses inputs não podes usar IDs repetidos. Nesse caso poderias fazer algo assim:

```js
var preco = document.getElementById('preco');
var quant = document.getElementById('quant');
var total = document.getElementById('total[]');
var table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var quant = e.target.matches('[name="quant[]"]') && e.target;
  var tr = quant.parentElement;
  while (tr = tr.parentElement) {
    if (tr.matches('tr')) break;
  }
  var preco = tr.querySelector('[name="preco[]"]');
  var total = tr.querySelector('[name="total[]"]');
  total.value = Number(preco.value) * Number(quant.value);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="50" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quant[]" class="form-control prc " min="1" max="10" step="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="50" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quant[]" class="form-control prc " min="1" max="10" step="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="50" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quant[]" class="form-control prc " min="1" max="10" step="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```